# system privilege issue

Tags: oracle, privileges, data-security

I have the user for example HR which has been granted very powerful system privilege "GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE"...This user used this privilege and granted some privileges to other users...Now I want to revoke "GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE" from HR and **also** identify what privileges and to whom did HR user grant(I want to revoke from them this privileges).

I know that oracle saves just grantee and privilege not grantor for system privileges(unlike object privileges) in the metadata...

If you have some idea please answer..

Thank you very much in previous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALL_COL_PRIVS view will show grantor
ALL_TAB_PRIVS view will show grantor
TABLE_PRIVILEGES view will show grantor

plus the USER versions of those..

**edit**:

to find the list of object privileges granted by HR use a query like this:

```
select * from all_tab_privs where grantor = 'HR';
```

i do not know of a way to check system level object grants

Comment: Thank you for your answer...But 
I don't know to whom did HR user give privileges so I don't know where should i select "ALL_COL_PRIVS" or "ALL_TAB_PRIVS" views(These views should be selected in these users,but unfortunately I don't know who they are)  to solve this you should select "ALL_COL_PRIVS_MADE" or "ALL_TAB_PRIVS_MADE" views in HR user,there I can see grantee(Identify to whom did HR user give OBJECT privileges)


BUT what is more important these views show me just OBJECT privileges not SYSTEM privileges, do you understand me?  I need system privileges